# Stream chain after Untar

Tags: bash, stream, tar

I would like to convert **efficiently** a couple of jpeg Images contained in a tar.gz to an x264 mp4 movie.

```
gzip -cd Monitor-1-xx.tar.gz|cpio -i --to-stdout|jpegtopnm|ppmtoy4m -F 4:1| \
>  x264 --crf 24 -o Monitor-1-xx.mp4 --stdin y4m -
```

The problem here is that, after cpio I have multiple jpg files in a single stream and jpegtopnm only converts the first one.

I would like to find a function to split the stream (or to get it pre-split). Then I would like to run jpegtopnm multiple times for each split. It is somewhat like what xargs does when I untar to disk first. Writing to disk is something I am trying to  eschew:

```
mkdir tmpMonitor && cd tmpMonitor && tar -xf ../Monitor-1-xx.tar.gz
find . -iname "*.jpg"|xargs -n1 jpegtopnm|ppmtoy4m -F 4:1| \
    x264 --crf 24 -o ../xx.mp4 --stdin y4m -
cd .. && rm -rf tmpMonitor
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tar` has a couple of options that may be useful here (I have GNU `tar`, so I apologize in advance for assuming you do in case you actually don't):

1. `--wildcards` - lets you pick files to extract from the tar using globs like `*.jpeg`
2. `--to-command` - pipe *each extracted file* to the given command.

So maybe something like this?

```
tar -xzf Monitor-1-xx.tar.gz --wildcards '*.jpeg' \
    --to-command="jpegtopnm|ppmtoy4m -F 4:1| x264 --crf 24 -o ../xx.mp4 --stdin y4m -"
```

Well I don't know much about `x264` so do consider that untested code.  I tested this using simple `.txt`  files instead of `.jpegs` and `cat -n` instead of `jpegtopnm` etc. The other thing is, I am guessing you want *separate* output files (one per jpeg), so it looks to me like `../xx.mp4` won't do... So assuming you want **separate** invocations of `jpegtopnm|ppmtoy4m -F 4:1| x264 --crf 24 -o ../xx.mp4 --stdin y4m -` for each file then you want a different output filename for `-o` right? - In which case, the following hack might work:

```
tar -xzf Monitor-1-xx.tar.gz --wildcards '*.jpeg' \
    --to-command="jpegtopnm|ppmtoy4m -F 4:1| x264 --crf 24 -o ../xx-`date +%H%M%S%N`.mp4 --stdin y4m -"
```

Comment: tar -xf Monitor-1-xx.tar.gz --wildcards '*.jpg' --to-command 'jpegtopnm' | ppmtoy4m -F 4:1| x264 --crf 24 -o Monitor-1-xx.mp4 --stdin y4m -

did the trick. Thanks a lot!